# Laravel eloquent fetching records based on values in the table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have a Tasks table that has a time field and a "minutes" field. I want to fetch only records based on the time and minutes field, something like so:

```
$tasks = Task::whereTime('time', '<=', Carbon::now()->addMinutes(DB::raw('minutes'))->format('H:i'))->get();
```

Let's say a task is due at 03:00 so the time field will be 03:00. Exactly 30 minutes before the task is due, I want to get a notification, so when the current time is 02:30.

So in this example, the "minutes" field is 30. Now, when fetching the records, I am using the above query. It does not work, but the below does work:

```
$tasks = Task::whereTime('time', '<=', Carbon::now()->addMinutes(30)->format('H:i'))->get();
```

Perhaps there is an easier/better way to approach this, but I want to get only the records from the database that will be used, and I do not want to perform multiple checks after fetching all records. So my question is, can this be done using eloquent or should I just fetch all records and perform some time checks after looping over all tasks?

Comment: The query handles _many_ rows, not a single row at a time. The reason the 2nd query works is you're hardcoding `30`, and the reason the top query doesn't work is that `DB::raw('minutes')` is not a minute value. You probably need a computed column in your database that is `time - minutes`, let's say `reminder_time`, which you could then target in your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use whereRaw so that you can customize the query.

```php
$tasks = Task::whereRaw('TIME(NOW()) >= TIME(SUBTIME(tasks.time, CONCAT("0:",minutes, ":0")))')->get();
```

ADDTIME is a function that adds a time to a time/DateTime format

for example, ADDTIME("00:00:00", "00:30:00"), adds 30 minutes to the initial time. I wrapped it in a time() function so I could compare it easily.
I also used the Concat function to create a time format like string

[Read more about ADDTIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate)

Comment: Very cool, just goes to show I should learn more about sql, I'll test this out and let you know if it works for me, and I will of course learn more about that ADDTIME function, thanks!

Comment: I accepted this answer but it is not giving me the expected results, it is returning all rows from the database. But at least this gives me an idea to play around with and learn, which is more than enough for me

Comment: Glad to hear that. I've made some updates in the query. it'll probably fix the problem. we made a mistake in the query. We should query for the rows where the current time is more than their time minus 30 minutes ( for example )

Comment: That is the exact query I also created after playing around with your answer, but it did not work for me, I'll try yours and play around with it some more if needed. Thanks!